# Distribution of random column vector

Tags: statistics

Let $\mathbf{Y} = (Y_1,...,Y_n$ be a random column vector with $\mathbf{Y} = A\mathbf{X}$ where A is an orthogonal matrix and $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,...,X_n)$ i.i.d. $N(0,1)$. How can I show that $\mathbf{Y}$ is again i.i.d. $N(0,1)$?

Comment: Check expected value and covariance matrix. For normal variables, uncorrelated implies independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X \sim \mathcal{MVN}(0 ,I)$, hence $AX$ is linear transformation of $X$, as such it remains multivariate normal. So, lets check its expectation and covariance
$$
E(AX)=AE(X)=A\cdot 0=0,
$$
and covariance
$$
cov(AX)=A'cov(X)A=A'IA=A'A=I,
$$
where the last sttep stems from the orthogonality of $A$, thus $A'=A^{-1}$.